# When Url Typed I need to fetch the single data in react js while calling api

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgTCv.png)

When I typed this `http://localhost:3000/hell/:2` the page loads but will not fetch a single item that has id 2

But When I clicked the button then the page shows the single item that has id 2
I need to show the data when I entered `http://localhost:3000/hell/:2` as URL

**""""""""""CODE Gets RUN but it was showing in a paragraph format so I had edit and made code easier to understand """""""""**

the code is --->>

At App.js-->

```
<div className="App">
    <div className='body'>
        <Router history={History}>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/hell/:id"><Hell/></Route>
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    </div>
</div>
```

At Hello.js-->

```
let {id} = useParams();
let di = id;
const [loading,setloading] = useState([false]);
const [posts,setposts] = useState([]);
const [search,setsearch] = useState("");
const [message,setmessage] = useState("");
const history = useHistory();

useEffect(()=>{
    const getload = async ()=>{
        setloading(true);
        const response = await axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/list/`);
        const message = "Error";
        setposts(response.data);
        setmessage(message);
        setloading(false);
    }
},[]);

console.log({di});

function inputhandler(a){
    id = a;
    history.push(generatePath("/hell/:id", { id }));
    setsearch(a);
}


return (
    <div>
        <h1>Find : {id}</h1>
            {
                posts.map((curElem) =>{
                    return(
                        <div>
                            <Link key={curElem.id} to={curElem.id} onClick={() => inputhandler(curElem.id)}>{curElem.title}</Link>
                        </div>
                    )
                })
            }

            {

            loading ?(<h4>Loading...{message}</h4>):(
            (posts.filter((value)=>{
                if(value.id===(search)){
                    return message;
                }
            })
                .map(item =><Help  key={item.id} title={id}></Help>)))
        }                
    </div>
)
}
```

Comment: There's not really enough info to answer your question, but assuming you have a restful api with typical routing that you're calling, you probably want to remove the `:` before the id. If you provide more info we may be able to answer whatever question you have.

Comment: Hello @DaveVanFleet Can I connect you in telegram I am getting some errors while posting so I posted this

Answer (score 0):

You've accessed the `id` route match param but then never used it.

You do not form the link targets correctly. Once you are linking correctly then there is no need for the extraneous `onClick` handler to set any `search` state with the `item.id` value since you can consume the linked `id` right from the params.

Remember to also call `getload` so the `posts` state is updated.

Hello.js

```
const history = useHistory();
const { id } = useParams(); // <-- current `id` from "/hell/:id"

const [loading,setloading] = useState([false]);
const [posts,setposts] = useState([]);
const [message,setmessage] = useState("");

useEffect(()=>{
  const getload = async ()=>{
    setloading(true);
    const response = await axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/list/`);
    const message = "Error";
    setposts(response.data);
    setmessage(message);
    setloading(false);
  }

  getload(); // <-- need to call to make the GET request
},[]);

return (
  <div>
    <h1>Find : {id}</h1>
    {posts.map((curElem) => {
      return(
        <div key={curElem.id}> // <-- React key on outermost element
          <Link
            // generate target path here
            to={generatePath("/hell/:id", { id: curElem.id })}
          >
            {curElem.title}
          </Link>
        </div>
      )
    })}

    {loading
      ? <h4>Loading...{message}</h4>
      : posts.filter((value) => value.id === id) // <-- filter by id
          .map(item => <Help key={item.id} title={id}></Help>)
    }                
  </div>
)
```

Comment: Hello Drew Can I connect you on Telegram? I am not getting what I am willing

Comment: @KKumar I am unsure what you mean by that, but have you concern over this answer or more issue?

Comment: Yeah thanks but i have something more issue that Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/list/single/6' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: @KKumar From what I understand that would be something your server sets, and is likely out-of-scope for this question.

Comment: @KKumar Sorry, it is late here for me and honestly you'd have better luck posting an additional question on SO regarding the backend server settings IMO.